# How to get current price of a custom contract token via cleos

Tags: smart-contract, cleos

I want to know the current price of the CET token via cleos. I can get the supply details using cleos:

```
$ cleos get currency stats eosiochaince CET
{
  "CET": {
    "supply": "900100052.0000 CET",
    "max_supply": "2000000000.0000 CET",
    "issuer": "eosiochaince"
  }
}
```

How do I get the current price for the CES/EOS pair? Is that even possible?

Comment: Who defines the price of the tokens? Which market is the reference you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need oracles to fetch the exchange rate of CET for an off-chain exchange, so you may be better off querrying Chaince. I don't think they're exposing a public API at the moment, but the price is communicated through websockets.